# trouble with codeigniter site -shows a hash in the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am listing data using Ajax but after that when i try to get into another menu i get hash in my URL, blocking the loading of link and i have to click on dashboard first and then another menu.http://localhost:8080/project/customers/customers_view#
How do i remove this # from url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag which you're clicking may have a hash attached to the href tag. that is

`<a href="#" class="nohash">hashify</a>`

change it to

`<a href="javascript:;" class="nohash">hashify</a>`

which is javascript void zero, which will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Chetan it removed the hash but if i click on menu it does not route to another page i am not getting any response on clicking.

Comment: can you please post the sample snippet of the code @D.Ramesh

Comment: removing unnecessary js files solved my problem.Like I have included some script files which are not being used on that particular page. Thanks Chetan for your response.